# How to automate release notes in Jira to populate a change log

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

We have been keeping an update log in a g-doc and maintaining it manually outside of Jira. The document keeps track of every release and the change notes. Is there a way to automate this in Jira?

Update log example:

7.16.395
        • Fix for error when applying stock from schedule tree.

7.16.394
        • Part configurations update when templates are selected.

7.16.393
        • Fix for subbing multiple order BOM items at once on the Part>Usage tab.
        • Fix for inventory counts not syncing.
        • Fix for marking order items complete.
        • Fixes for pick list quantity calculations and prioritization.
        • Template changes updated to part configurations with the 'Sync w/ templates'

Answer (score 0):

you can use Jira Automation for it.

Create an automation rule which will automatically trigger along with a new release.

to do so,

- goto project setting
- select Automation
- Create a new Rule
- Select "Release new Version" in the When section
- Use lookup issue action and add JQL filters like project='xyz' and fixVersion= '{{release.name}}' .....
- finally select a notification action like slack/email or create a wiki page

Tempalte for notification action :

```
{{#lookupIssues}}
>  <{{url}} | {{key}}> :  {{summary}}
{{/}}
```

Let us know if it helps